# Why high energy physicists study complexity?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-gravity

Recently, studying complexity is a trend in high energy physics. I have read there are two motivations behind these studies. First, Einstein-Rosen bridge behind the horizon keeps evolving even after thermalization. The dual quantity of this growth on QFT on the boundary is conjectured to be complexity. Second, entanglement entropy approach as an emergent of space cannot provide a time part of metric in the bulk. Complexity can do this.

What I am asking is a clarification on these points and even more physical motivations supporting these complexity studies.

Comment: Could you give a definition of complexity in the sense that you are using it, or provide a link?

Comment: I assume meaning as per https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437402/relation-between-quantum-entanglement-and-quantum-state-complexity

Comment: @doetoe I don’t know! That’s really ambigiuous

Comment: This is not an answer, but you may be interested in talks from the most recent PiTP, particular from Lenny Susskind (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OXdhV5BOcY) and Scott Aaronson (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCChR2HgCgc) if you haven't seen these already.